# Симулятор xcode iphone 4s

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

Подскажите. 
купил макбоок, установил xcode 5.0.2, до этого устанавливал ось на простой комп, а туда ставил 4 весию xcode, 
при компиляции на компе версия 4 xcode, симулятор был iphone 4, т. е. полностью внешний вид, кнопочка с низу и т. д. все соответствует. 
а в версии 5.0.2 какая-то неразбериха. внешний вид совершенно другой, т. е. он вообще отсутствует. в симуляторе присутствует такие модели iphone retina 3.5-inch, iphone retina 4-inch и iphone retina 4-inch 64-bit. 
так какой симулятор нужно использовать для компиляции под iphone 4s? или тут что-то надо докачивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SDK нет симулятора конкретной модели iPhone, они делятся только по разрешению и размеру экрана, а также версии системы, но в любом случае используют все ресурсы вашего мака. Можно симулировать предупреждения и нехватке памяти и прочие системные уведомления или действия, но чтобы протестить именно на 4S вам нужен iPhone 4S

Докачивать можно только поддержку более ранних deployment targets. Чтобы появилась "кнопочка" выберите iPhone Retina 3.5 Inch, запустите приложение и нажмите Cmd + 1. 
Если Minimum deployment target выставлена в iOS 6.0, будет доступен симулятор 3.5 Inch без ретины

Comment: Спасибо, я понял что модель надо выбирать непосредственно в самом симуляторе, а операционная система может быть разная у одинаковых устройств.
http://hkar.ru/nzpS

Answer (score 0):

Выбрать версию iOS не пробовали?

[image: Снимок экрана]

Comment: дело в том, что у меня там не чего не предлагает выбрать, у вас я вижу стрелочки, а у меня даже стрелочек нету 

http://hkar.ru/nyTZ